# Google Stun server stun.l.google.com change IP?

Tags: stun

I was using the Google Stun server by IP 74.125.143.127, but since 21/09/2021 it seems Google changed the IP of DNS stun.l.google.com.
I know I should use DNS rather fixed IP.
Any guys have some confirmation about the IP change?
tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I know I should use DNS rather fixed IP*

**Yes**.  That's the answer. Full stop.  Don't hardcode IP addresses to services in your app. The whole point of DNS... well, you know this right?

Some recent DNS lookups:

```
stun.l.google.com:   74.125.197.127
stun1.l.google.com: 173.194.193.127
stun2.l.google.com: 172.253.112.127
stun3.l.google.com: 173.194.77.127
stun4.l.google.com: 172.217.215.127
```

Testing the old IP you referenced that's not in the DNS entries above:

```
>stunclient 74.125.143.127
Binding test: fail
```

Testing the IP address that's currently being returned:

```
>stunclient 173.194.193.127
Binding test: success
Local address: 192.168.1.18:55004
Mapped address: 1.2.3.4:55004
```

Comment: Kurento (webrtc server) doesn't let you configure DNS, only an IP.
So you'd need to do the lookup in an external process and reconfigure as needed.